# ConcurrencyHashMap and BashProcessing

Tags: java, multithreading

First some abstraction. My problem can be modelized as the following :

I have a room with N doors, and anyone can drop package in the room. Once there is a given number of package in the room, I want them to be shipped away while keeping the doors open.

Using Java 1.8, I'm working on a multi-threaded application where any thread can add items to my [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) object.

I want to regularly dump my ConcurrentHashMap when it reaches a certain size without blocking the threads adding items to the Map. Dumping including several operations which are costly.

I thought of the following solutions :

- Check the size of the HashMap each time I add something, and if the map reached the max size It'll copy itself to an other map, reset and continue. I am not sure It'll be thread safe
- Create a wrapper function for the put() method of ConcurrentHashMap which is synchronized. I believe I'll loose any advantage of using a ConcurrentHashMap
- Use a ArrayListBlockingQueue with my batch size as size. It'll block when it will be full, but I'll need something to process it later.
- Something else I didn't think of.

I am basically self taught regarding Java Threads and I'm looking for suggestions and ways to tackle my problem.

Comment: you need the size for the HashMap as a set number or something more lax and how many possible concurrent dump?

Comment: I don't understand the thing about "N doors". What does that mean? When does a door close? Who can use which door?

Comment: @Zeromus : I don't have any limits regarding the number of concurrent dump. My hard limit is more like "EAch 500 object in my HashMap, I need to dump them

Comment: @AndyTurner : The doors are an analogy for the threads filling up my HashMap. There can be as many thread as possible (usually I use the same number as my core count)

Comment: @Shade right, but what does "closing a door" mean? Is that putting something into the map? And "keeping the doors open": what is that? "Keeping them open" implies they weren't closed in the first place.

Comment: @AndyTurner I want to be able to dump the content of my map without stopping items from being stocked in it. Closing a door means blocking the threads which tries to add items to the ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: Can you put multiple items through the same door before they are shipped? If not, can I use a different door if I find the door I wanted to use already has an item in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't really understand the doors analogy. It sounds to me like you simply need a [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#remainingCapacity()):

- "Somebody dropping a package in the room" is just a call to `queue.offer(obj)`
- "Shipping the items away" is just a consumer thread taking `S` items from the queue, and then doing something with those objects:

  ```
  while (true) {
    Object[] objs = new Object[S];
    for (int i = 0; i < S; ++i) {
      objs[i] = queue.take();  // Perhaps with a timeout?
    }
    doSomethingWithObjects(objs);
  }
  ```

In this way, you can keep on offering items to the queue ("keeping the doors open") while the consumer thread is processing them (provided you create the queue with sufficient capacity).

Comment: The door analogy may has been quite bad. To answer your previous question, a door can stay "open" a long time and put multiples items until they are shipped away. 
I'll doodle with your code tomorrow at work and come back to you. Thanks for the input !